# Integrate Facebook Authentication into Spring Security in FacebookApp

Tags: java, security, facebook, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a working web application that uses username/password SpringSecurity configuration. Now I want to port it into a simple Facebook application. For some reason, I want to do authentication by using facebook access token returned, as well as keeping the username-password validator.

In details, I would check the user facebook access token for authentication, returned by:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[my_api_key]&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]&client_secret=[my_api_secret]&code=[code]`

The user don't need to provide any username/password since they already logged in with facebook. But I would like to keep (username/password) spring security configuration so that the users can sign in in my original website.

Does SpringSecurity support this kind of authentication? If the answer is yes, I wonder how it can be done? Does I need to write custom authentication provider(s) to do it?

**UPDATE**: In the end, we have customize the way SpringSecurity authenticate, so that it accept access_token as a authentication parameter by extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (declaring it as `formLoginFilter`)

Comment: @HaveAGuess: I have updated my answer in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's another project from Spring: [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) which is very useful.

It supports multiple social networks. I successfully used it to authenticate to Facebook. I then wrote a small function to log a Facebook user into my Spring Security context:

```
protected void authenticate(UserDTO user){
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(getRequest()));
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

`UserDTO` needs to have a username and (generated) password attribute and needs to be saved in database so your `user-service` (from Spring security) can retrieve it.

Comment: Bart Vangeneugden its not working...showing errors..I included spring api too..Is there any api which is also to be added

Answer (score 5):

You are thinking along the right path...

Here is an article about multiple authentication providers with spring security (so e.g. one form login, one facebook login and one login with open-id).

http://thoean.com/programming/java/multiple-authentication-provider-with-spring-security/

Hope that helps :D